# M-x compile on remote server

Tags: shell, emacs, compilation

I'm running GNU Emacs on Windows 7 and compiling over ssh on a Linux compilation server.

Can emacs communicate with an open SSH shell and run `Make` in it?

If possible, I don't want to open a new shell each time I `Make`.

Comment: What about running emacs over SSH? Is that an option?

Comment: No. I need to edit local-only files on a regular basis.

Answer (score 3):

I recently added this to my /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

```
Host server.somewhere.org
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
```

Here server.somewhere.org should be replaced with your Linux PC.
It speeds up Emacs TRAMP tremendously because the SSH handshake is done only once (when Emacs first connects).

Probably this is possible in Windows as well.

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid reconnecting each time I compile because the build system requires it's own initialization. I'm upvoting anyway for usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

You could try <kbd>M-x tramp-compile</kbd>.

See http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/tramp_5.html#SEC24

Comment: Looks interesting, but doesn't work because I'm editing the files on a shared network drive. Is there an ssh implementation that is compatible with Emacs on Windows? I use Cygwin's ssh, but I don't want to re-install Emacs itself under Cygwin.

Comment: Scratch that. plink.exe comes with putty.